# Unsigned char* is converted to byte when generate interop file

Tags: c#, mfc, com-interop

I have a MFC Client application and COM service dll.
In previous, we use MFC client to call the function of COM service

MFC Client:

```
FunctionA()
{
    unsigned char replyValue[100];
    HRESULT hr = FunctionB(attribute, replyValue);
}

HRESULT FunctionB(BSTR attributeName, unsigned char* value)
{
    HRESULT hr = serviceObj->GetAttrValue(attributeName, value);    
}
```

COM service:
idl:

```
[id(8), helpstring("method GetAttrValue")] HRESULT GetAttrValue([in] BSTR serviceName, [out,retval] unsigned char* pReturnValue);
```

code:

```
STDMETHODIMP GetAttrValue(BSTR serviceName, unsigned char* pReturnValue)
{
    ...
}
```

Now we are going to covert the MFC client to a C# application, we still want to reuse the COM service. So we use following command to generate an interop dll

```
Tlbimp ComService.dll /out:Interop.ComService.dll​
```

But when I check the interop dll in C# project, I found the function declare has changed.
What I see in C# object Browser:

```
byte GetAttrValue(string serviceName)
```

The return value is byte, not a byte array or string.

How should I modify to get the correct value in C# application. I don't have rights to modify the com service code, can I get the actual value by only changing my C# code.

Comment: `LPCTSTR` in a COM interface is **always** wrong. You'll have to take a step back and understand what an ABI is, and why `LPCTSTR` cannot be used to describe one.

Comment: The idl is exactly defined to return (out) an unsigned char which is a byte. tlbimp does exactly what's expected, it builds a .NET method that returns a byte (out, retval). How could anyone know the method implementation will write an array? Your native idl and code is wrong. If you can't change it, you're doomed.

Comment: `HRESULT` is not a normal return value, it's an exception code. The return value is in `pReturnValue`. So the conversion is correct

Comment: Thanks @SimonMourier, the COM Service project is maintained by another team. How should I suggest them to update this interface? Wrap the unsigned char array into VARIANT?

Comment: If you want to type a bit more you can use a SAFERRAY but a VARIANT is ok since you can  pretty much return many things with it, including a SAFEARRAY. You can easily create a SAFEARRAY of bytes using SafeArrayCreateVector (VT_UI1, ...): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-safearraycreatevector or even easier using InitVariantFromBuffer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propvarutil/nf-propvarutil-initvariantfrombuffer